# Design a text box with multiple file attachment option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to design a text box which needs the option to add multiple files. we can take a reference of skype text box to send a message and add files.

I created some text box but I am not able to design a text box with better user experience.

one of the examples is as below.

```html
    <textarea #cName  class="cmnt-control" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
```

but I want to create a text box like skype for reference below I have added an image.[image]

can anyone please help me in to design a text box which should have the attach multiple file option and send icon inside the text box.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `textarea` in div and adding `icon` in div using `position:absolute;`

```css
.cmnt-control{
  position:relative;
}
.cmnt-control textarea{
  padding:10px 55px 10px 20px;
  width:calc(100% - 75px);
  resize: none;
}
.iconuser{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.icon{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.icon.icon2{
  right:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="cmnt-control">
  <i class="fa fa-user iconuser"></i>
  <textarea #cName cols="50" rows="1"></textarea>
  <i class="fa fa-search icon"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus icon icon2"></i>
</div>
```